# Powering bookcase spotlights from existing outlet

Tags: wiring

Installing a cabinet and upper bookcase on wall where outlet exists (but is never used).  Wanted to fish a line from top of bookcase (thru wall) down to new wall switch and on to outlet box to use that to power a couple of small decorative lights being mounted on headboard of new bookshelves.  It sounds straight forward but wanted to make sure I wasn’t getting into any code issues.  Thanks!

Comment: What room does this receptacle serve?

Comment: Wire from top of bookcase into the wall.....if you wanted the outlet up the wall further, run a new line and install a new outet at the desired location. Or use an extension cord from the top location to the outlet.